# Add fallback image for images giving a 404 error on nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, image

In case of an image (png,jpg,gif) missing thus giving a 404 error, I would like Nginx to send back a fallback image e.g. https://example.com/fallback.png

I tried the following with no success

```
location ~* ^/[^/]*/(.*)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
   try_files $uri https://example.com/fallback.png =404;
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: If this server is `https://example.com`, you should be using: `try_files $uri /fallback.png =404;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for the suggestion. That didn't do the trick either. I don't know if this happens due to the site being a WordPress one.

Comment: What exactly happened?